# eslint-plugin-react-hooks : Unclear Installation

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, eslint, create-react-app

The [npm webpage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks) for eslint-plugin-react-hooks, or the [github page](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin-react-hooks/README.md), says, under "installation",

> **Note: If you're using Create React App, please use react-scripts >= 3 instead of adding it directly.**
> Assuming you already have ESLint installed, run:
> npm install eslint-plugin-react-hooks --save-dev

Can anyone please explain what I am supposed to do if I'm using Create React App? Some of my projects use Create-React-App, others do not. Does this instruction apply to all my projects? And how do I "use react-scripts >= 3"? What is a "react-script"?

`npm install` I can understand. The note, less so. TIA.

Comment: `react-scripts` are default build tools for react. They installed through create react app. Check your `package.json` to see versions